# brew uninstall node error high sierra

Tags: node.js, homebrew, node-modules

I try to uninstall node with brew, but I run into the following issue that I do not seem to get solved.

When I run `brew uninstall node` , I get the following error message:

```
Uninstalling /usr/local/Cellar/node/10.5.0_1... (7,893 files, 34.2MB)
Error: Directory not empty @ dir_s_rmdir - /usr/local/Cellar/node/10.5.0_1
```

Any idea how to solve this issue? Can I just delete this file?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem. I did a recursive `chown` on the `/usr/local/Celler/node` folder setting it to `MyUser:staff` (changing MyUser to your user, obviously) and that allowed me to successfully run `brew uninstall node`. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install node using [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm). It is easier and you can install multiple version of node.

Answer (score 0):

Run `sudo chown -R "$USER" "$(brew --prefix)/Cellar"`